# How to calculate number of words in a string in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have simple Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    'one apple',
    'banana',
    'box of oranges',
    'pile of fruits outside',
    'one banana',
    'fruits'])
df.columns = ['fruits']
```

how to calculate number of words in keywords, similar to:

```
1 word: 2
2 words: 2
3 words: 1
4 words: 1
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

IIUC then you can do the following:

```
In [89]:
count = df['fruits'].str.split().apply(len).value_counts()
count.index = count.index.astype(str) + ' words:'
count.sort_index(inplace=True)
count

Out[89]:
1 words:    2
2 words:    2
3 words:    1
4 words:    1
Name: fruits, dtype: int64
```

Here we use the vectorised [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split on spaces, and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `len` to get the count of the number of elements, we can then call [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to aggregate the frequency count.

We then rename the index and sort it to get the desired output

**UPDATE**

This can also be done using `str.len` rather than `apply` which should scale better:

```
In [41]:
count = df['fruits'].str.split().str.len()
count.index = count.index.astype(str) + ' words:'
count.sort_index(inplace=True)
count

Out[41]:
0 words:    2
1 words:    1
2 words:    3
3 words:    4
4 words:    2
5 words:    1
Name: fruits, dtype: int64
```

**Timings**

```
In [42]:
%timeit df['fruits'].str.split().apply(len).value_counts()
%timeit df['fruits'].str.split().str.len()

1000 loops, best of 3: 799 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 347 µs per loop
```

For a 6K df:

```
In [51]:
%timeit df['fruits'].str.split().apply(len).value_counts()
%timeit df['fruits'].str.split().str.len()

100 loops, best of 3: 6.3 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6 ms per loop
```

Comment: At first I was confused how could we use `str.len` after the `str.split` which turns each element into a list instead of str.   So, I checked the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and realized the function works as long as the element is of list-like types.     Hope this clarification might be helpful for laymen like me who had the same question.

Answer (score 17):

You could use `str.count` with space `' '` as delimiter.

```
In [1716]: count = df['fruits'].str.count(' ').add(1).value_counts(sort=False)

In [1717]: count.index = count.index.astype('str') + ' words:'

In [1718]: count
Out[1718]:
1 words:    2
2 words:    2
3 words:    1
4 words:    1
Name: fruits, dtype: int64
```

---

**Timings**

`str.count` is marginally faster

<sub>**Small**</sub>

```
In [1724]: df.shape
Out[1724]: (6, 1)

In [1725]: %timeit df['fruits'].str.count(' ').add(1).value_counts(sort=False)
1000 loops, best of 3: 649 µs per loop

In [1726]: %timeit df['fruits'].str.split().apply(len).value_counts()
1000 loops, best of 3: 840 µs per loop
```

<sub>**Medium**</sub>

```
In [1728]: df.shape
Out[1728]: (6000, 1)

In [1729]: %timeit df['fruits'].str.count(' ').add(1).value_counts(sort=False)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.58 ms per loop

In [1730]: %timeit df['fruits'].str.split().apply(len).value_counts()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.99 ms per loop
```

<sub>**Large**</sub>

```
In [1732]: df.shape
Out[1732]: (60000, 1)

In [1733]: %timeit df['fruits'].str.count(' ').add(1).value_counts(sort=False)
1 loop, best of 3: 57.6 ms per loop

In [1734]: %timeit df['fruits'].str.split().apply(len).value_counts()
1 loop, best of 3: 73.8 ms per loop
```