# Empty strings in pandas series counted as one when getting the number of words in strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, apply

I have a problem when counting the number of items in a pandas string series when there is no sting in a row.

I´m able to count the number of words when there are one ore more items per row. But, if the row has no value (it´s an empty string when running 
pd.['mytext'].str.split(',')), I´m getting also one.

These answers are not working for me [Answer 1 to a solution which gives one for an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483470/how-to-calculate-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-dataframe/52918606?noredirect=1#comment92747031_52918606) [Answer 2 to a solution which gives one for an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970561/splitting-a-column-of-strings-and-counting-the-number-of-words-with-pandas).

How can I handle this in a pandas one liner? Thanks in advance.

Taken the example from the first answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['one apple','','box of oranges','pile of fruits outside', 'one banana', 'fruits'])
df.columns = ['fruits']
```

The verified answer was

```
count = df['fruits'].str.split().apply(len).value_counts()
count.index = count.index.astype(str) + ' words:'
count.sort_index(inplace=True)
count
```

Which gives

```
Out[13]:  
0 words:    1
1 words:    1
2 words:    2
3 words:    1
4 words:    1
Name: fruits, dtype: int64
```

I want a zero for the second string but every solution tried gave me a one.

Comment: No, it does not. Please explain how this happens. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Done, the example above gives a small overview.

Comment: I'm thinking you misunderstood what was being output. The output is telling you the number of rows with N words. (1 row has 0 words, 1 row has 1 word, 2 rows have 2 words, 1 row has 3 words, and so on). Do you want the number of words per row instead?

Comment: Yes, but Martyna had already a solution to my problem. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm sure they did. But that isn't a great solution, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you suggest a better solution? I´m open for any improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `split()` empty string returns empty list, however when you use `split(',')` empty string returns list with empty string. This is why the example is not working with your solution.

You can try something as below: First you split string by comma as based on your example I assume this is your case. Then if split returns list with empty string function returns 0, otherwise returns length of list with words.

`pd.Series(['mytext', '']).str.split(',').apply(lambda x: 0 if x==[''] else len(x))`

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split` and count the elements with `str.len`:

```
df['wordcount'] = df.fruits.str.split().str.len()
print(df)
                   fruits  wordcount
0               one apple          2
1                                  0
2          box of oranges          3
3  pile of fruits outside          4
4              one banana          2
5                  fruits          1
```

Replace `' '` with `','` for your actual data.

Comment: This gives me ones where I have empty strings. Maybe I was giving the wrong example from the other thread. My dataframe looks like df = pd.DataFrame(['banana', 'apple', '', 'another,tropical,fruit'])

Strings in each row, separated by commas and sometimes empty strings.

Comment: @Mikey how would it give 1? I just showed you an example in my data where it shows 0 in row with index 1. Can you please explain clearly why that does not work? I also told you to change the delimiter from space to comma for your problem.

Comment: I did change the delimiter. Please can you try this example:

    test = pd.DataFrame(['banana', 'apple', '', 'another,tropical,fruit'])
    test.columns =['text']
    test.text.str.split(',').str.len()

it gives me a one for the third entry where I want a zero

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you're referring to `str.split(',')`, but the examples are for `str.split()`. The function has different behaviour based on whether you have an argument.

Which are you actually trying to do?

Comment: My strings are separated by a comma. There is no blank between the words. That´s why I referred to my my split version.